# Error when trying to call SAP HANA stored procedure from service side

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script, s4hana, xsjs

I am trying to call a SAP HANA hdbprocedure from my service side using below code.

```
var con = ConLib.getHDBConnection();
var uploadStmt = con.loadProcedure("_SYS_BIC" , "procname");
var result = uploadStmt("samplefield1",  "samplefield2", {"DATA":[{"id1":"id_1001","id2":"id_2001","year_col":"2018"}, {"id1":"id_1002","id2":"id_2002","year_col":"2019"}]})
```

The procedure takes below paramaters as input.

```
PROCEDURE procname (
IN field1 VARCHAR(100),
IN field2 VARCHAR(100)
IN in_table_data "schema_name"."hdbdd_file_name.table_type"
){}
```

The in_table_data is defined as below in hdbdd_file_name.hdbdd file.

```
Type table_type {
id1 : String(100);
id2 : String(100);
year_col : String(4);}
```

I am getting below error when I call the procedure from my service side.

```
" Error occured in processRequest method $.hdb.Connection.executeProcedure: Parameter at  position 3 is not of type that can be processed "
```

Could you please suggest what needs to be changed either at the DB side or service side to fix this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm under the impression that the definition of the array in your calling statement is incorrect:

`var result = uploadStmt("samplefield1",  "samplefield2", {"DATA":[{"id1":"id_1001","id2":"id_2001","year_col":"2018"}, {"id1":"id_1002","id2":"id_2002","year_col":"2019"}]})`

instead, try it like so:

```
var result = uploadStmt("samplefield1"
                      , "samplefield2"
            , [{id1: 'id_1001', id2: 'id_2001', year_col: '2018'}
             , {id1: 'id_1002', id2: 'id_2002', year_col: '2019'}]
                       )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This solved the issue.

Comment: Great to hear that. Don't forget to mark the answer as "correct".